# How to resolve a Future in flutter (dart)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to write a functions which returns until an upload has been finished. If it is possible it would be good if I could also add a timeout.

```
 waitForUpload() async {
     uploader.result.listen((result) {
        // return waitForUpload
     }
 }
```

I just don't find how to write this in dart. To make it more clear: In JS the code would look like this:

```
async waitForUpload() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    uploader.result.listen((result) {
        resolve();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: what is "waitForUpload"?

Comment: I mean what is the data type?

Comment: `Future<bool>` which returns 'true' if no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 9):

Using a Completer would be more straightforward.

```dart
Future time(int time) async {

  Completer c = new Completer();
  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: time), (){
    c.complete('done with time out');
  });

  return c.future;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Stream.single` implements the behavior I want. Looking at [implementation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/single.html), you can see  `future._complete(result);` is called inside the `listen` method which resolves the future.

Comment: Can you explain why this is wrong? Downvoting a questions which has been upvoted before without giving any comment is not useful at all.

Comment: Thanks @MarcS82 I think it's my use case!

Answer (score 0):

You can create some class like this to mimic js promise.

```
class Promise {
  Completer _c = Completer();

  bool _holdExecutionFlag = true;

  void holdExecution() async {
    _holdExecutionFlag = true;
  }

  void resumeExecution() {
    _c.complete();
    _c = Completer();
    _holdExecutionFlag = false;
  }

  Future waitForExecution() async {
    if (_holdExecutionFlag) await _c.future;
  }
}
```

and utilise it like this

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() async {
  Promise promise = Promise();
  promise.holdExecution();

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), promise.resumeExecution);
  await promise.waitForExecution();
  print('success');
}
```